# Как вывести нужное количество определенного символа по числу?

Tags: php

Допустим, при числе 3, мне нужно вывести
3 символа +++ и т.д, число может быть разное, как реализовать это на php?

Answer (score 4):

Использовать https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Пример

```
<?php
echo str_repeat("-=", 10);
?>
```

выведет:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```